# Is it possible to set two exposure values and set them on a loop?

Tags: exposure, timelapse, moon, double-exposure

I'm trying to capture a time lapse of the moon rising and would like to set one exposure time for the moon and one for the foreground. Is it possible to save two exposure values or do I have to switch back and forth manually?

Comment: What kind of camera are you using? The correct answer to your question is very much dependent upon the capabilities of the specific camera you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the camera, but look at bracketing settings. Most cameras allow you to take 3 exposures - one correct (as metered), one underexposed and one overexposed, but some allow 2 exposures too - e.g. one as metered and one overexposed (which seems to be what you're looking for). If you enable bracketing before starting the timelapse, the camera should bracket each shot.

Answer (score 0):

Most DSLR cameras have a built-in intervalometer to shoot timelapses, but they don't offer very good control over their parameters. Also, the support for bracketing during timelapses is very model/manufacturer-dependent.

For what you want to shoot, you might consider getting a dedicated time lapse intervalometer. These devices usually also allow you to increase or decrease the exposure slowly over the timelapse (known as *bulb ramping*, or *bramping*).